# Base project dll reference not found in upper layers

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my current architecture I have the following project organization...

An class library named "MyBaseProject" and different web application projects with reference to MyBaseClassLibrary.

In MyBaseProject I added a 3rd party dll (Newtonsoft.Json)

Now all web projects are throwing the exception "Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json or one of its dependencies."

I do not want to add the Newtonsoft.Json in all my web projects, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The most obvious behaviour here is that you have not set the output directory for your projects, and thus they're defaulting to their own, individual locations. Thus, while `MyBaseProject` references and copies `Newtonsoft.Json`, your other projects only copy over `MyBaseProject`. Because of this, the `MyBaseProject.dll` located in the folder with the other projects does *not* have a copy of `Newtonsoft.Json`, and since it's not in the GAC, the reference fails.

The easiest solution is to make all your projects output to the same directory. I'm personally fond of `$(SolutionDir)\bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)`. This will ensure that when `MyBaseProject.dll` is built and carries along any of its requirements, your other projects will be able to get those requirements via the same folder without incident.

Comment: Actually the directory output was already set. I removed the reference of MyBaseProject and added again, it worked.